# Grouping by multiple "keys"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am quiet new to using databases and I need to query a given mongoDB. The data is stored in documents like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d2aac59a5020e18762be2"),
  "configId" : "5b7d29f659a5020e18762be1",
  "deviceId" : 1,
  "timestamp" : 700,
  "posX" : 5,
  "posY" : 12,
  "valueId" : 1,
  "value" : 310.24
}
```

What I need is the newest document (the one with the highest timestamp) for every configId, for every deviceId, for every valueId.

My first idea was to sort them by timestamp and then somehow group the data using the aggregate function. But I was not able to find examples with grouping by multiple keys.
I could filter my data in my application later on, but I think there should be a "mongo-style" way to do this.

Thanks for any advice that brings me closer to a working "mongo-style" solution,

Comment: Try `db.colname.aggregate([{$sort:{timestamp:-1}}, {$group:{_id:{configId:"$configId",deviceId:"$deviceId",valueId:"$valueId" }, doc:{$first:"$$ROOT}}}])`

Comment: ah, I just missed the doc:{$first:"$$ROOT} part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Veeram , I think there is something wrong with the sorting or the $first. I allways receive the first (oldest / lowest timestamp) value. I also tried $last and {timestamp:1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by multiple keys [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

For Example :

```
{"$group" : {"_id" : {"configId" : "$configId","deviceId" : "$deviceId"},---do what you want ($sum or $push etc..)--}}
```

*Here I have 2 data's with two different timestamps 700 and 900* it's working fine check.

**MY DATA**

```
   /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d2aac59a5020e18762be2"),
    "configId" : "5b7d29f659a5020e18762be1",
    "deviceId" : 1.0,
    "timestamp" : 700.0,
    "posX" : 5.0,
    "posY" : 12.0,
    "valueId" : 1.0,
    "value" : 310.24
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d619994983bedbfda191f"),
    "configId" : "5b7d29f659a5020e18762be1",
    "deviceId" : 1.0,
    "timestamp" : 900.0,
    "posX" : 5.0,
    "posY" : 12.0,
    "valueId" : 1.0,
    "value" : 310.24
}
```

**THIS IS MY QUERY**

```
db.col.aggregate([
            {"$sort" : {"timestamp" : -1}},
            {"$group" : {"_id" : 
                {"configId" : "$configId","deviceId" : "$deviceId","valueId" : "$valueId"},
                "data" : {"$first" : "$$ROOT"}
                }
            }
])
```

**THIS IS MY OUTPUT**

```
    {
    "_id" : {
        "configId" : "5b7d29f659a5020e18762be1",
        "deviceId" : 1.0,
        "valueId" : 1.0
    },
    "data" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d619994983bedbfda191f"),
        "configId" : "5b7d29f659a5020e18762be1",
        "deviceId" : 1.0,
        "timestamp" : 900.0,
        "posX" : 5.0,
        "posY" : 12.0,
        "valueId" : 1.0,
        "value" : 310.24
    }
}
```

Comment: How do get the newest document? As far as I understood your answer it is only about grouping the data.